# Objective-C enum error?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, enums

I've defined an enum at the top of my class header:

```
enum PresetSeq{kSeqClear=0, kSeqAllBeats, kSeqAllTicks};
```

But when I try to declare a method for that class using the enum.

```
-(void)quickSetSeq:(PresetSeq)pattern  forChannel:(long)ch;
```

I get the error:  expected ')' before 'PresetSeq'

If I typedef the enum instead:

```
typedef enum  {kSeqClear=0, kSeqAllBeats, kSeqAllTicks} PresetSeq;
```

Then the compiler is happy, but I don't remember having to do that in C/C++.

Do enums have to be typedef's in Obj-C?

Thanks

Steve

P.S. - I saw other posts about Obj-C enums, but not why this simple case fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are C `enum`s. (Remember Objective-C is just a strict superset of C).

To define an enumerated *type*, you **must use** `typedef`.

However, if you do not need to have a standalone *type* (without the `enum` prefix) to collectively refer to that enum, then you do not need `typedef` and you can just declare it like this:

```
enum PresetSeq {
  kSeqClear, 
  kSeqAllBeats, 
  kSeqAllTicks
};
```

So, in your case, you can do it either way:

```
typedef enum {
  kSeqClear,
  kSeqAllBeats,
  kSeqAllTicks
} PresetSeq;

-(void)quickSetSeq:(PresetSeq)pattern  forChannel:(long)ch;
```

Or without `typedef` and using the `enum PresetSeq` syntax as shown above:

```
-(void)quickSetSeq:(enum PresetSeq)pattern  forChannel:(long)ch;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you happen to know if omitting both the typedef and enum syntac is legal in C++? I have some old C++ code that seemed to accept it

Comment: Yes, ommitting `struct` and `enum` (or not `typedef`ing `struct`s and `enum`s) is perfectly legal C++.  As is adding the `struct` or `enum` label.

Comment: Thanks Max, that explains a lot of what I'm seeing in old code.

Comment: Thanks, I also got this issue, and I changed my source to `.mm` solved   this problem

Answer (score 4):

If you use:

```
enum  PresetSeq {kSeqClear=0, kSeqAllBeats, kSeqAllTicks};
```

then you *must* use the `enum` name:

```
-(void)quickSetSeq:(enum PresetSeq)pattern  forChannel:(long)ch;
```

Your initial error is because there *is* no `PresetSeq` type, just a `enum PresetSeq` one.

When you do the `typedef` version, that creates a type alias `PresetSeq` that you can use.

It's exactly the same as:

```
struct X {int a;};
typedef struct (int a;} Y;
```

In that case, you can use `struct X` or `Y` as a type but you cannot use `X` on its own.

Comment: There ya go, @Steve, now you do :-) Not that it matters, since I've hit my daily rep cap.